# Как обновить данные TextView из Java класса?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Есть класс MainActivity реализует интерфейс UpdateView

```
public interface UpdateView {

    void update(String name, String lastname);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateView {

@BindView(R2.id.first_name) TextView firstName;
@BindView(R.id.last_name) TextView lastName;

private User userInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    User userInfo = new User();
    userInfo.init(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        Log.d("User info ", userInfo.getFirstName());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void update(String name, String lastname) {

    firstName.setText(name);
}
```

}

Класс User в которым данные берется из  API. Для получения данных из сети использую библиотеку okHttp (асинхронный вызов).

```
public class User {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private UpdateView updateView;


public  void init(Context context){

    getDataFromAPI();
}
private void getDataFromAPI(){

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get").newBuilder();
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("user_ids", "210700286");
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter( "fields", "bdate");
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("v", "5.60");

    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            //Log.d("Response", response.body().string());
            parseUserInfo(response.body().string());

            updateView = new MainActivity();
            updateView.update(firstName, lastName);

        }
    });
}

private void parseUserInfo(String string) {

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(string);
        JSONArray response = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
        JSONObject userObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
        String name = userObject.getString("first_name");
        String lastName = userObject.getString("last_name");

        //Log.d("2", name + " " + lastName);
        this.firstName = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

Получаю рантайме

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Как обновить TextView когда данные успешно получены (onResponse())?

Если запрос данных из API перенесу из User в MainActivity и внем запущу

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        //Log.d("Response", response.body().string());
        parseUserInfo(response.body().string());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            firstName.setText(....);
        }
    });

    }
```

работает.

Answer (score 1):

Activity может создавать только операционная система. В вашем коде `new MainActivity()` принципиально неверно. А второй вариант, когда запрос происходит из уже созданной `MainActiivty`, верен.